# How to get every nth element from each group in a grouped data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, grouping

I have a big data frame with a column, with a group name, which is grouped with **dplyr**. So multiple rows have the same group name. To reduce the data, I would like to extract every nth element starting from the first element from each group. Is there any **R way** without loops?

Subsetting every row with a sequence, has the problem that often the first row of each group is missed. e.g.

```
data[seq(1, nrow(data), 10), ] # Some groups start without the first row.
```

Input:

```
   Val Group
1  1.0 Fruit
2  2.0 Fruit
3  3.0 Fruit
4  1.5 Veg
5  2.8 Veg
6  4.2 Veg
7  5.1 Veg
```

Output (every second element, be aware of 3rd row!):

```
   Val Group
1  1.0 Fruit
2  3.0 Fruit
**3  1.5 Veg**
4  4.2 Veg
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(Group) %>%
  slice(seq(1, n(), by = 2))
```

This gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   Group [2]
    Val Group
  <dbl> <fct>
1   1   Fruit
2   3   Fruit
3   1.5 Veg  
4   4.2 Veg
```

Comment: Or with a counter - `dat %>% group_by(Group) %>% filter(row_number() %% 2 == 1)` , which should be a bit quicker on big data.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a base R way:

```
DF$ID_by_Group <- ave(DF$Val, DF$Group, FUN =  seq_along)
DF[DF$ID_by_Group %in% seq(1,3, by = 2), ]

  Val Group ID_by_Group
1 1.0 Fruit           1
3 3.0 Fruit           3
4 1.5   Veg           1
6 4.2   Veg           3
```

The `ave()` function creates an ID by group. The second statement is just filtering based on the `ID_by_Group` that we created.

Note, we could do it all at once and/or remove the added column:

```
DF[ave(DF$Val, DF$Group, FUN =  seq_along) %in% seq(1,3, by = 2), ]

DF$ID_by_Group <- ave(DF$Val, DF$Group, FUN =  seq_along)

DF[DF$ID_by_Group %in% seq(1,3, by = 2), -3]
DF[DF$ID_by_Group %in% seq(1,3, by = 2), -grep('ID_by_Group', names(DF))]
DF[DF$ID_by_Group %in% seq(1,3, by = 2), c('Val', 'Group')]

#all provide:

  Val Group
1 1.0 Fruit
3 3.0 Fruit
4 1.5   Veg
6 4.2   Veg
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative choice is `data.table`:

```
> setDT(data)                   
> data[(rowid(Group) %% 2) == 1]
   Val Group                    
1: 1.0 Fruit                    
2: 3.0 Fruit                    
3: 1.5   Veg                    
4: 4.2   Veg
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option to select every nth row in each group using `ave` exploting the recycling property

```
n <- 2

df[as.logical(with(df, ave(Val, Group, FUN = function(x) 
                      c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, n - 1))))),  ]

#  Val Group
#1 1.0 Fruit
#3 3.0 Fruit
#4 1.5   Veg
#6 4.2   Veg
```

This returns a warning message since the vector returned is not of the same length but I think it can be ignored.

Or using @thelatemail's idea from the comment which doesn't give the warning message.

```
df[as.logical(with(df, ave(Val, Group, FUN = function(x) 
                   seq_along(x) %% 2 == 1))), ]
```