# dplyr: How to slice row1 of group1, row2 of group2, row3 of group3, ...rowN of groupN

Tags: r, dplyr, slice

This question is inspired by this question: [How to use conditional filtering of a data frame in R when trying to retain non-duplicated values in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66339251/how-to-use-conditional-filtering-of-a-data-frame-in-r-when-trying-to-retain-non/66339971?noredirect=1#comment117433455_66339971)

How can we slice in subsequent groups (1,2,3,4...n) the corresponding rows (1,2,3,4....n).
In this simplified example the first dataframe should result in the second:

```
library(tidyverse)
# tibble
df <- tibble(
  group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
  value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
)
```

[image] should result in this [image]

So far I have tried different options with `slice` like `slice(seq(1, n(), by = 2))` from here: [How to get every nth element from each group in a grouped data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066541/how-to-get-every-nth-element-from-each-group-in-a-grouped-data-frame).
Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  slice(cur_group_id())
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
# # Groups:   group [5]
#   group value
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1
# 2     2     2
# 3     3     3
# 4     4     4
# 5     5     5
```

Comment: Perfect. Context dependent expressions completely new to me! Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to use `cur_group_id()` in case of `group_by(group1, group2)`

Comment: `cur_group_id` will number the groups you have, whatever they are, from 1 to the number of groups. It's not dependent on how many grouping columns you have or what their values are (other than that the default ordering of the groups will be in ascending order of the grouping values).

Answer (score 2):

and a data.table solution to be complete ;-)

```
library( data.table )
setDT(df)[, .SD[.GRP], by = group]
```

explanation from the help file:
`.SD` is a data.table containing the Subset of x’s *[wimpel: here x == df]* Data for each group, excluding any columns used in by (or keyby).
`.GRP` is an integer, length 1, containing a simple group counter. 1 for the 1st group, 2 for the 2nd, etc.